# get a List of Max values across a list of lists

Tags: c#, linq, list, max

I have a `List<List<double>>` and I need to find a List MyList where MyList[0], for instance, is the Max of all the first elements of the List.
Example, just to be clear:
First list contains (3,5,1), second contains (5,1,8), third contains (3,3,3), fourt contains (2,0,4). 
I need to find a list with (5, 5, 8). 
I do NOT need the list (5,8,3,4).

Of course i know how to do it with nested for cycles. 
I'd like to know if there's a linq way and believe me i don't know where to start from.

Comment: Show your non-LINQ approach, please. It should make more clear what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to flatten a list of list to a single list with the maximum values for each index?

Comment: Will you always have the same # of items in each list, and will it be a constant number of items each time? For ex: do you know that you will always have x items in each list?

Comment: BateTech: I was actually going to add that yes, all the lists will always have the same number of elements but this element can vary.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Matt Burland: yes, that is what I need. I will also need the equivalent with Min, but that will work the same.

Comment: MarcinJuraszek: in psuedocode i would write:
Declare List<double> MaxValues;
Initialize MaxValues with N times Double.MinValue . N is the number of elements in all the lists;
Cycle over all the List;
Cycle over all the element of one list;
If Mth element is bigger than the Mth element in MaxValues, substitute it;

Comment: John Saunders: i read that post. I wouldn't call it a "consensus" and in this case, i would feel compelled to write my next question without the "Linq" tag and forcing the tag on the title. My (probably wrong) reasoning is that "related" questions appear with only their title on the column on the right, and if i am looking for a similar question, i immediately see a question using linq if "LINQ" appears at least in the title. Nothing against adding the tag of course, but if they are mutually exclusive, i would prefer it to appear in the title. Thank you anyways for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 // Here I declare your initial list.
 List<List<double>> list = new List<List<double>>()
 {
     new List<double>(){3,5,1},
     new List<double>(){5,1,8},
     new List<double>(){3,3,3},
     new List<double>(){2,0,4},
 };

 // That would be the list, which will hold the maxs.
 List<double> result = new List<double>();


 // Find the maximum for the i-st element of all the lists in the list and add it 
 // to the result.
 for (int i = 0; i < list[0].Count-1; i++)
 {
     result.Add(list.Select(x => x[i]).Max());
 }
```

**Note**: this solution works only, when all the lists that are contained in the list have the same number of elements.

Comment: Christos, first of all thank you for answering.I choose (so far) your answer because it's faster than the simple nested for (when there are many data) and much much faster than the other solution proposed. I think there's a typo in your solution, you need to write list[0].count-1 i suppose. Unfortunately, your solution is valid only when all lists have the same length, but this,as i wrote in comments, is my situation, so it's ok. Isn't there a way to write also this "for" in your solution as a linq statement? not a requirement, just out of curiosity

Comment: @JohannesWentu use `var result = Enumerable.Range(0, list.Length).Select(i => list.Max(x => x[i])).ToList();` to get rid of `for` loop.

Comment: @Johannes Wentu thank you for letting me know about my mistake. Seeing the comment of Marcin, I would say that this I would use, in order to avoid the use of the for.

Answer (score 4):

```
var source = new List<List<int>> {
    new List<int> { 3, 5, 1 },
    new List<int> { 5, 1, 8 },
    new List<int> { 3, 3, 3 },
    new List<int> { 2, 0, 4 }
};

var maxes = source.SelectMany(x => x.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }))
                  .GroupBy(x => x.i, x => x.v)
                  .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                  .Select(g => g.Max())
                  .ToList();
```

Returns `{ 5, 5, 8}`, which is what you need. And will work when source lists have different number of elements too.

**Bonus**

If you need version for `Min` too, and want to prevent code duplication, you can go a little bit functional:

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> GetByIndex<TSource>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source, Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource> selector)
{
    return source.SelectMany(x => x.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }))
                 .GroupBy(x => x.i, x => x.v)
                 .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                 .Select(g => selector(g));
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> GetMaxByIndex<TSource>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{
    return GetByIndex(source, Enumerable.Max);
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> GetMinByIndex<TSource>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> source)
{
    return GetByIndex(source, Enumerable.Min);
}
```

Comment: Marcin, thankx for your answer too. It's working,meaning it gives the correct solution and thank you for the bonus too. Unfortunately, from my tests, it seems much slower (factor 10 or 20) than Christos' answer, even if yours is cleaner and more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this topic is answered long time ago, I'd like to put here another solution I've made up with Linq, shorter than this [other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735097/1507014) :

```
List<List<int>> mylist; //initial list of list

List<List<int>> mins_list = mylist.Aggregate(
    (x, cur) => cur.Zip(x, (a, b) => (a.Value > b.Value) ? a : b).ToList()
).ToList();
```

This very simple code is just aggregating every sub-list into a list of minima. Note that the internal `ToList` is mandatory as `Zip` is deferred.

You can encapsulate the code in an extension method, and do the same trick as MarcinJuraszek to generate other similar computations (min, max, mean, std, ...).

Answer (score -1):

If always you know how many elements present in your lists,you can use this approach:

```
var result =  new[]
        {
            list.Select(a => a[0]).Max(), 
            list.Select(a => a[1]).Max(),
            list.Select(a => a[2]).Max()
        };
```